# Add specific attribute Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-data, jquery-attributes

I want to add an attr `data-columns` into `<div id="grid">`

Like this : `<div id="grid" data-columns>`

I try it but it does not work : `$('#portfolio').attr("data-columns");`

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set an attribute, you need to give it a value:

```
$('#portfolio').attr("data-columns", "yourvalue");
```

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

First you have to give some values to data-columns

```
<div id="grid" data-columns="some Value">
```

Then access it like

```
var x = $('#grid').attr("data-columns")
```